# PHP UNIX Timestamp not iterating to the same value

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am facing a problem with unix timestamps, php and mysql and would be great if somebody could explain to me where I am going wrong or if I am not then why I am getting the figures that I am getting.

When I use jquery datepicker to pass the date in year-month-date format to php the hour and minutes have been set by default of 23:00:00 in the timestamp even though I am not passing this infromation in the request. So my question is where is this phantom 23:00:00 appearing from?

Workflow:

**Using datepicker:** datepicker -> php -> mysql = TIMESTAMP which has time set at 23:00:00.

**Without using datepicker:** php->mysql = TIMESTAMP with the correct hour and minutes.

Thanks for reading.

EDIT: PHP code as requested:

```
PHP code:

$setdatealpha = $_POST['datepickeralpha'];
$setdatealpha = strtotime($setdatealpha);

// With this, I am inserting into MySQL like so:


$sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE (DATE_FIELD) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s',$setdatealpha);
$stmt->execute();
```

Now when I read the entered information back and convert it to date time format via date('Y-m-d',timestamp), the date entry correct and the time entry has the 23:00:00 value.

This does not occur if I do a standard converstion via strtotime (date);

Comment: Can you paste here the php code that handle it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off of the information currently available, I would suggest that you make sure each timestamp is in UTC. I always run into timezone issues.

For PHP, like: `$current_timestamp = strtotime($date." UTC");` 
For jQuery datepicker I found this stackoverflow thread: [How to obtain utc time in jQuery datetimepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963621/how-to-obtain-utc-time-in-jquery-datetimepicker)

Comment: Nice tip. However, please note that (if not used carefully) this can lead to situations where website user enters e.g. `March 30th` and gets `March 29th` back, which would be confusing to say the least. You must use the same time zone every time.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, time zone.

First of all, let's clarify the context. `strtotime()` produces a Unix timestamp, which you apparently feed `DATE_FIELD` with. If that works, it means that the column is an `INTEGER`. In the case, you're doing something afterwards to display the date and you haven't shared that part—also, MySQL is innocent here because it doesn't even know what `DATE_FIELD` is meant to be date.

While `strtotime()` can be fed with a raw date, it needs to generate time as well. It can't do it unless it knows the time zone. Additionally, when you have an integer variable with a Unix timestamp and you want to display it as proper date you also need to know the time zone.

In both cases, if you don't provide it PHP will use a default value:

```
var_dump(date_default_timezone_get());
```

So you'll possibly want to set a known one with e.g. [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php). However, your users may have a different time zone than you so yours would be meaningless to them. Since you prompt the user for a raw date (without time) it's possible that time is actually not relevant to the question. In such case, you may want to:

1. Make `DATE_FIELD` of `DATE` type.
2. Avoid `strtotime()` and similar stuff. You may want to use [checkdate()](http://php.net/checkdate) instead.